# Почему нельзя "положить" str[i] в стек?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Stack {
  private:
    int maxSize, top;
    char *stack_array;

  public:
    Stack(int n) {
        stack_array = new char[n];
        maxSize = n;
        top = 0;
    }
    ~Stack() {
        delete[]stack_array;
    }

    void push(char a) {
        if (top < maxSize)
            stack_array[top++] = a;
        else {
            cout << "Stack is FULL!";
        }
    }

    char pop() {
        if (top != 0)
            return stack_array[--top];
        else {
            cout << "Stack is EMPTY!";
        }
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
            cout << stack_array[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string str;
    Stack N1(20);

    cout << "Enter your mathematical expression:  " << endl << endl;
    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) // Ошибка тут: '<=' : signed/unsigned mismatch
    {
        N1.pop(str[i]);
        N1.print();

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш `pop` принимает `std::string,` а в этой программе вы по очереди подсовываете ему `char'ы`, из которых состоит строка. Кстати, да, у вас "перепутались" операции `push` и `pop`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать почему у меня pop() не работает? Что там неправильно? Не подскажете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что надо заменить

```
N1.pop(str[i]);
//На
N1.pop(str.substr(i,1));
```

Стэк для лексического анализатора калькулятора продолжает свое победоносное шествие.

Comment: Все еще не компилирует, увы =/

Comment: Конечно не компилирует, потому что вы забыли поставить в конце фигурную скобку.

Comment: сегодня столько с кодом работал, что уже не вижу простые самые ошибки. Спасибо!

Comment: Ваша проблема(как и многих других новичков) в том что вы не умеете правильно интерпретировать сообщения об ошибках компилятора. Не стоит лезть на форум не попытавшись разок вникнуть в смысл того что там написано. Дебаг вашего кода в обоих случаях занял у меня ровно 10 секунд просто потому что я открыл output, прочитал сообщение об ошибке и правильно его понял.

Comment: @igumnov со временем думаю научусь) кстати, можете взглянуть, почему у меня pop() не работает??? Он совсем ничего не берет =/

Comment: Все это бесплатный дебаг в последний раз. Больше не буду отвечать/комментировать. Надоело.

    char pop() //Объявление
    
    N1.pop(str[i]); //Вызов. pop работает без параметров. Наверное вы имели в ввиду push.